# OutlookのVBAで予定表削除がされない

Tags: vba

OutlookのVBAを使って、会議開催通知の予約をキャンセルを受信したら予定表から予定を自動的に削除するコードを書いてみています。
しかし、★印のところからエラーに成って動かないようです。

VBAの超初心者ですが教えて頂けませんでしょうか？

```
    Set tmpItem = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(buf(i))
    If tmpItem.MessageClass = "IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Request" Then
        Set tmpAppoint = tmpItem.GetAssociatedAppointment(True)
        Set tmpMeeting = tmpAppoint.Respond(olResponseAccepted, True)
        tmpMeeting.Send
    ElseIf tmpItem.MessageClass = "IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Canceled" Then
        Dim meetItem As MeetingItem
        Dim apptItem As AppointmentItem
        Set meetItem = objItem
        Set apptItem = meetItem.GetAssociatedAppointment(False)★
        apptItem.MeetingStatus = olMeetingCanceled
        apptItem.Send
        apptItem.Delete
    End If
```

Comment: ★行の前でSet meetItem = objItemとありますが、objItemはどこで設定されていますか？　また、エラーのメッセージも追記してください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
Outlookのルールで動かしたいので下記のように書いています。
Public Sub DisplaySubjectByRule (ByRef objItem As MeetingItem)
エラーは、"実行時エラ-91: オブジェク卜変数または Withブロック変数が設定されてません。"となってしまいます。

Comment: それでしたら、DisplaySubjectByRuleを呼ぶ時点で適切なMeetingItemが渡っていないのではないかと思われます。

Comment: 遅くなりましたが、ありがとうございました。
他にも検討してみたいと思います。